# Creating Views - WITH CHECK OPTION

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have a couple of questions regarding with check option in MySQL:

1) I know `with check option` doesn't add records that do not satisfy the `WHERE` clause in the subselect query used to define a view, but what happens if `with check option` is not selected? Why would rows that don't satisfy the `WHERE` clause be added?

2) What is the difference between `LOCAL` / `CASCADED` `with check option`?

Comment: which server are you using? MSSQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it more around when you perform an UPDATE. When you perform an UPDATE against a base table, and subsequently do a SELECT, the rows you just updated are still there.

Now imagine a view that selects rows from a base table, based on their ID being between 2 and 5, and the user runs these queries:

```
SELECT * from View
UPDATE View set ID = ID + 3
SELECT * from View
```

Now, suddenly, rows have disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Without `WITH CHECK OPTION`, updating (`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`MERGE`/`DELETE` etc) a viewed table will cause its underlying base tables to be updated, regardless of the `WHERE` clause of the `VIEW` (assuming the DBMS considers the view to be updateable). If you `INSERT` a row into a `VIEW` that didn't satisfy the `WHERE` clause then refreshed the `VIEW` the newly-inserted row would not be visible in the `VIEW`. The `WITH CHECK OPTION` would prevent such an 'odd' situation from happening but there is more to it than that.

Consider a `VIEW` that is created to allow a certain user (group of users, application, etc) to view only a subset of rows in a table e.g. to allow them to view data for staff while preventing them from viewing the details of executive employees: revoke read privileges on the base table for this user and instead grant them on the view. The `WITH CHECK OPTION` allows you to do the same for write privileges, in this case it would prevent an `INSERT` to tehe view if it would create a executive employee row.

Similar techniques can be used to enforce 'row-level' constraints e.g. that a company can only have one president by forcing the `INSERT` via a `VIEW` whose `WHERE` clause only allows for one employee per company.

---

> how can you define the condition that " a company can only have one president "

Here's a simple example (no FKs etc) using standard SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
( company_id CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  employee CHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  job_title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL );

 CREATE VIEW Presidents
 AS
 SELECT *
   FROM Employees
  WHERE job_title = 'president'
    AND 1 >= ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM Employees e
                WHERE e.job_title = 'president'
                GROUP
                   BY e.company_id )
WITH CHECK OPTION;

INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ( 'Acme', '1', 'president' );
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES ( 'Acme', '2', 'president' );
```

The second insert fails because it would make the count of presidents for company `Acme` would be greater than one, so the 'subquery' part of the query would cause the new president to be removed from the view's resultset and the transaction is effectively rolled back.

Comment: can you put an example of what you said in the last paragraph ? An updatable view has some restrictions i.e. having no  `group by` , `having` ,`aggrgate function` etc . Then how can you define the condition that " a company can only have one president  " ?

Comment: This is incorrect example. MySQL will not let you create this view definition at the first place. I tried to execute the same in MySQL and received the error while creating the view - "CHECK OPTION on non-updatable view"

Comment: @anurag to be fair I said it was Standard SQL, rather than the mySQL dialect. I would have hoped in the 11 years that have passed since my answer that the mySQL product would have caught up with the 1992 version of the SQL Standard!